# Java - Game thread freezes when switching panels in CardLayout

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working on a 2D game in Java, using no libraries.

In my games InputHandler (used for movement, quitting, etc,.), when I press "Escape," the button to switch to the pause menu, and then hit the "Back" button, my player can no longer move.

PausePanelGUI:

```
public class PausePanelGUI extends JPanel {

public PausePanelGUI(LayoutManager layout, Game game) {
    super(layout);

    JButton backBtn = new JButton("Back");
    backBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                CardLayout c = new CardLayout();
                c = (CardLayout)(GameLauncher.getMainLauncherPanel().getLayout());
                c.show(GameLauncher.getMainLauncherPanel(), "Game");
                game.resume();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    backBtn.setBounds(250, 200, 150, 25);

    this.add(backBtn);
}}
```

Escape button in InputHandler:

```
if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
        try {
            CardLayout c = new CardLayout();
            c = (CardLayout)(GameLauncher.getMainLauncherPanel().getLayout());
            c.show(GameLauncher.getMainLauncherPanel(), "Pause");
            game.pause();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Pause and Resume methods:

```
public synchronized void resume() {
    System.out.println("Game resumed!");
    this.isPaused = false;
}

public synchronized void pause() {
    System.out.println("Game paused!");
    this.isPaused = true;
}
```

Run method:

```
while (isRunning) {
        if (!this.isPaused) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;
            lastTime = now;
            boolean shouldRender = true;

            while (delta >= 1) {
                ticks++;
                update();
                delta -= 1;
                shouldRender = true;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (shouldRender) {
                frames++;
                repaint();
            }

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer >= 1000) {
                lastTimer += 1000;
                frames = 0;
                ticks = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help? :3

Comment: What does your player input code look like? Have you tried debugging through it to see if it is being called when you press keys after you unpause the game?

Comment: I have not, I will test that as well as post input code.
EDIT: My keys are not being called after unpausing :0

Comment: I haven't read your code, but I think you shouldn't be using CardLayouts (as swing interferes with your graphics and such).

Comment: The `while (isRunning) ...` is not in [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (I hope) ? and I'm not sure to understand why your pause/resume function are `synchronized` because it should be called only from EDT.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it simply by adding requestFocus();. The thread wasn't actually freezing, my InputHandler just wasn't being registered.